# Using Rails 5 and minitest, how can I access a record that was created in the test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, minitest

I have this test that was passing before I switched the Note table to use UUID:

```
test "SHOULD create note AND redirect to Notes#index(SINCE null folder_id) WHEN only body is provided IF logged in as account:owner" do
  sign_in @user
  assert_difference('@user.account.notes.count') do
    post notes_url(@user.account.hash_id), params: { note: { body: @note_by_user_no_folder.body } }
  end
  assert_redirected_to notes_url(@user.account.hash_id, anchor: Note.last.id)
end
```

But after switching to UUID, I'm getting the following failure error:

```
Failure:
NotesControllerTest#test_SHOULD_create_note_AND_redirect_to_Notes#index(SINCE_null_folder_id)_WHEN_only_body_is_provided_IF_logged_in_as_account:owner [/Users/chris/Dropbox/Repositories/keepshelf/test/controllers/notes_controller_test.rb:117]:
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/11111111/notes#9dc409ff-14cc-5f64-8f5f-08e487f583ee> but was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/11111111/notes#34dac6b7-46af-4c5c-bff7-760ffa77edf6>.
Expected "http://www.example.com/11111111/notes#9dc409ff-14cc-5f64-8f5f-08e487f583ee" to be === "http://www.example.com/11111111/notes#34dac6b7-46af-4c5c-bff7-760ffa77edf6".
```

I take this as that since the UUID's do not follow an order, that the new Note I am creating in the "post notes_url(..." does not end up being the "last" one that `Note.last.id` finds.

How can I set the anchor: to `record_that_was_just_created.id` ?

Comment: You can try finding the last created record using `created_at` (but in db it is rounded to seconds so a few of them might end up with the same time). Or you can pass in a uniq attribute and use `find_by` for that attribute.

Comment: thanks. doing Note.order(created_at: :desc).last.id is not being consistent (I assume for the reason you describe). i don't know how i would do a find_by without having access to the record that was just created.

Comment: When you call `post` in your test, do you not know what'll be in the params? Say  `{ body: "special body" }` and then just `find_by(body: "special body")`.

Comment: IMHO, its time to take a step back and consider that may be your test is incorrect :) you shouldn't depend on increment IDs to verify results anyway. A better test would be to check the contents of the note you are writing and see if it appears on the note page. That being said, if you absolutely must, you can sort the notes by `created_at`  timestamp, get the ID and take it from there..

Answer (score 1):

I figured this out. apparently there is a way to access the controller's instance variables in the test so I got it to work by changing the assert_redirected_to to

```
assert_redirected_to notes_url(@user.account.hash_id, anchor: controller.instance_variable_get(:@note).id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Late answer here, I'm glad you got the result you need!

... *in case anyone else reads this looking for the test practices* ...

The short answer is - you should always know what data is being used in the test ... because you make it.  The most common 3 ways ...

In the `setup` method where you

- Load a **fixture** `@account = Accounts(:first)`  (needs matching entry in yaml file)
- Call **factorybot gem** (see thoughtbot's page for how to)
- Explicitly write `@account = @user.account.build(field: value, field2: value)`

So, you have the literal answer to your question - it's bad practice to test against uncertain data - `Shaunak` was saying that too.

The above is probably enough - but your detail oriented testing should be in unit tests - where you are not calling against db & making your tests the slowest possible version.  Your integration level stuff should just test that creation was successful - you already know the data going in there works.

For the best experience you probably want unit tests something from the 3 methods above in `setup` & use `@account` in the test like so to test against the validations you are about to create ...

So the unit test would be ...

```
setup
  @account = @user.account.build  # avoid hitting db unnecessarily versus create
  @account.field = value
  @account.field2 = value2
end

def test_details_pass_activerecord_validations
  signin @user
  @account.test_specific_fields = value  # stuff not all the tests use
  assert @account.valid?  # trigger all the activerecord validations, but not db 
end
```

From there your integration ...

```
test "SHOULD create note AND redirect to Notes#index(SINCE null folder_id) WHEN only body is provided IF logged in as account:owner" do
  # Your setup method above should have most of the intialization 
  # ... basically @account = @user.account .note would be setup, but not inserted

  signin @user
  assert_difference('@user.account.notes.count') do
    post notes_url(@account), params: { note: { body: @account.note.body } }
  end
  assert_redirected_to notes_url(@account, anchor: @account.whatever_field)
end
```